# Tk Treeview Focus(). How do I Get Multiple Selected Lines?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, focus, ttk

ttk.treeview.focus() returns the iid of a single line. The treeview box allows you to select multiple lines. How do I get a list of iids for the selected lines?

Answer (score 10):

`ttk.treeview.focus()` returns the current focus item. That means the item that was last selected. The function you are looking for is `ttk.treeview.selection()`. This returns a tuple of the selected items.

Comment: It actually returns a tuple, not a list.

Answer (score 6):

Use `ttk.treeview.selection()`.

It gives the selected items. See also other Treeview methods with `selection` prefix such as,

```
selection_add
selection_remove
selection_toggle
```

See the example below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Tk


def insert(tree, value):
    tree.insert('', tk.END, value, text=value)

root = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(root)

insert(tree, '1')
insert(tree, '2')
insert(tree, '3')

tree.pack()
children = tree.get_children() 
tree.selection_set(children)
tree.selection_toggle(children[1])

# uncomment line by line to see the change
#tree.selection_toggle(children)
#tree.selection_remove(children[1])

print(tree.selection())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! - the documentation I had did not have that method in it.